# How to change map view's orientation for navigating the users?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am implementing the navigation manager in javascript for learning purposes where I would like to navigate the user based on the calculated route. If the start and destination points are located in south, north directions respectively, then the marker for the start position appears in the bottom of the map's viewPort and the target maker would appear on the top by default. In contrast, assume the following situation where the start and destination point's are located in north, south directions respectively. I would like to change the orientation of the view upside down in order to keep the start position in the bottom and destination on the top (Similar to commercial android apps).

I tried two different methods to change the cameraview but I couldn't achieve it due to the following reasons.

**Method-1:**
The first method is based on startInteraction which is given in the following link where I couldn't find any options to set the HEADING angle

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-render-renderengine-interactionmodifiers.html

Code:

```
var map = new H.Map(...);
var viewPort = map.getViewPort();
viewPort.startInteraction(H.map.render.RenderEngine.InteractionModifiers.HEADING);
```

**Method-2:**
I am trying to change the camera view according to the given position, orientation data which will be processed by the renderer. The setCameraData method from the following link works fine with the parameters zoom, position  {H.geo.IPoint} and the renderer updates the map correspondingly.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-viewmodel.html#h-map-viewmodel__setcameradata

When I change the orientation of the virtual camera, i observe absolutely no difference in the map though roll, pitch, yaw properties are assigned with some values (I tried both the degrees (type used by HERE maps) and radians).

Code:

```
var map = new H.Map(...);
var viewModel = map.getViewModel();
var data = {'zoom': 16, 'position': curLoc, 'pitch': 0, 'yaw': 0, 'roll': 45.0}; // type - {H.map.ViewModel.CameraData}
viewModel.setCameraData(data);
```

Note: I have also tried updating the view with setViewBounds() method but I couldn't set the map's view upside down.

Best Regards,

Jeyaprakash Rajagopal

Answer (score 0):

The JS API itself is just supporting one map view and that means north is on the top.